# View controls do not show up using Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

Even I'm a Swift beginner, it should be simple but I don't know why. I'm not keen to use Storyboard so I decided to go for the Interface Builder. After adding several elements into my view controller, they are not showing up when I run my app. The following is my code:

`window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) 
let home = HomeViewController()
window!.rootViewController = home
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()`

I've already set `HomeViewController`to the `File's Owner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would be this line:

```
let home = HomeViewController()
```

You should change it to

```
let home = HomeViewController(nibName: "Whatever the name of your xib file is", bundle: nil)
```